# How to filter a object list inside of a object list by name property in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to do a task that is proving difficult. How can I achieve the goal to filter a list of list in Kotlin? I was looking here with filter and map but was impossible to can do it.

I have this data class.

```
data class CategoryModel(
    val collections: List<CollectionModel>,
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)

data class CollectionModel(
    val id: Int,
    val image: String,
    val name: String
)
```

That I want to do is get a list of CategoryModel that have only the collectionModel that match a substring with a specific collectionModel.name.

This is the code that I've try but if collectionModel have two element I get both, and I want only the element that contains the substring:

```
collection.forEachIndexed { index, element ->
    for (collectionModel in collection[index].collections) {
        if (collectionModel.name.contains(textToSearch.capitalize())) {
             collectionSearch.add(collection[index])
        }
    }
}
return collectionSearch
```

UPDATE 1

```
collection.reduce{ acc, list ->  list.collections.filter { it.name.contains(textToSearch.capitalize()) } }
```

give this error:

[image: ![image error]

Comment: How have you tried it yourself? Can you show us the code and the error message(s) that occurred?

Comment: are you getting the list from somwhere and you want to filter it?

Comment: Yes I've tried. I've updated the question

Comment: I get the list from the back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's cleanest to create new `CategoryModel` instances as you filter. These are nice immutable models anyway.

```
val criterion = textToSearch.capitalize()
val filtered = collection.mapNotNull { sourceCategory ->
    with (sourceCategory.collections.filter { criterion in it.name }) {
        if (isNotEmpty())
            CategoryModel(this@with, sourceCategory.id, sourceCategory.name)
        else
            null
    }
}
```

Explanation:

`mapNotNull` means we are creating a new list containing only the results of the lambda that are not null. In the lambda, we either create a CategoryModel for the new filtered list, or return null to skip it when it didn't have any items with the desired criteria.

In the `with` statement we create a new filtered list of the acceptable CollectionModels and if it isn't empty, we pass it to the new copy of the source CategoryModel.

Answer (score 2):

This feels somehow hacky, because the following code creates new objects of `CategoryModel` using a filtered list of `CollectionModel`, but it seems to work. It returns a `MutableList<CategoryModel>` because

```
var collectionSearch: List<CategoryModel> = categoryModelList.filter {
    // check each CategoryModel
    categoryModel -> categoryModel.collections.filter {
        // check if there are CollectionModels with a name containing capitalized textToSearch
        collectionModel -> collectionModel.name.contains(textToSearch.capitalize())
    }.isNotEmpty() // only consider those with a non empty result
}.toList()  // get all the matching CategoryModels as List<CategoryModel>
```

Calling it in a `fun main` like this

```
fun main() {
    // minimal data sample
    var categoryModelList: List<CategoryModel> = listOf(
        CategoryModel(listOf(CollectionModel(1, "collMod A", "nameA")), 1, "catMod A"),
        CategoryModel(listOf(CollectionModel(1, "collMod B", "nameB")), 2, "catMod B")
    );

    // sample text to be found
    val textToSearch: String = "b";

    // here it is
    var collectionSearch: List<CategoryModel> = categoryModelList.filter {
        categoryModel -> categoryModel.collections.filter {
            collectionModel -> collectionModel.name.contains(textToSearch.capitalize())
        }.isNotEmpty()
    }.toList()

    println(collectionSearch)
}
```

results in the following output:

```
[CategoryModel(collections=[CollectionModel(id=1, image=collMod B, name=nameB)], id=2, name=catMod B)]
```

which appears desired.

## EDIT

After having clarified the requirements, the following extension function of `List<CategoryModel>` might be sufficient, though it feels not perfect:

```
fun List<CategoryModel>.getModified(condition: String): List<CategoryModel> {
    var result: MutableList<CategoryModel> = mutableListOf();

    this.forEach { categoryModel ->
        // get a list of matching CollectionModels
        val cols = categoryModel.collections.filter { collectionModel ->
            collectionModel.name.contains(condition.capitalize())
        }
        // if the list is not empty
        if (cols.isNotEmpty()) {
            /*
             * add a new item to the result using the filtered collections
             * and the other (unmodified) attributes
             */
            result.add(CategoryModel(cols, categoryModel.id, categoryModel.name))
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

When I call it like this

```
fun main() {
    // minimal data sample
    var categoryModelList: List<CategoryModel> = listOf(
        CategoryModel(mutableListOf(CollectionModel(1, "collMod A", "nameA"),
                            CollectionModel(2, "collMod B", "nameB")
                            ), 1, "catMod 1"),
        CategoryModel(mutableListOf(CollectionModel(3, "collMod B", "nameB")), 2, "catMod 2"),
        CategoryModel(mutableListOf(CollectionModel(4, "collMod BB", "nameBB"),
                            CollectionModel(5, "collMod C", "nameC")
                            ), 3, "catMod 3"),
        CategoryModel(mutableListOf(CollectionModel(6, "collMod A", "nameA"),
                            CollectionModel(7, "collMod D", "nameD")
                            ), 4, "catMod 4")
    );

    // sample text to be found
    val textToSearch: String = "b";
    // print the source
    println(categoryModelList)
    // and the modified list in order to compare them
    println(categoryModelList.getModified(textToSearch))
}
```

the output appears to be the desired one:

```
[CategoryModel(collections=[CollectionModel(id=1, image=collMod A, name=nameA), CollectionModel(id=2, image=collMod B, name=nameB)], id=1, name=catMod 1), CategoryModel(collections=[CollectionModel(id=3, image=collMod B, name=nameB)], id=2, name=catMod 2), CategoryModel(collections=[CollectionModel(id=4, image=collMod BB, name=nameBB), CollectionModel(id=5, image=collMod C, name=nameC)], id=2, name=catMod 3), CategoryModel(collections=[CollectionModel(id=6, image=collMod A, name=nameA), CollectionModel(id=7, image=collMod D, name=nameD)], id=3, name=catMod 4)]
[CategoryModel(collections=[CollectionModel(id=2, image=collMod B, name=nameB)], id=1, name=catMod 1), CategoryModel(collections=[CollectionModel(id=3, image=collMod B, name=nameB)], id=2, name=catMod 2), CategoryModel(collections=[CollectionModel(id=4, image=collMod BB, name=nameBB)], id=2, name=catMod 3)]
```

which means there are only `CategoryModel`s left that had matching `CollectionModel`s in `collections` and only those are left there, all others have been removed.

Comment: I'm getting elements in collectionModel that not contains the textToSearch.....

Comment: Hmmm... really? Then switch the `isNotEmpty()` to `isEmpty()` and try again, please...

Comment: with isEmpty() I get all the elements unless the correct item

Comment: @S.P. yes, I was expecting that... The original logic with `isNotEmpty()` should work. If not, there must be a different problem. Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: The object model is not exactly in this way. Try with this:   var collection1 = CollectionModel(1, "xxxxx", "Rice")
    var collection2 = CollectionModel(1, "xxxxx", "Pasta")

    var collectionListtoAdd = arrayListOf(collection1, collection2)

    var collectionToSearch = CategoryModel(collectionListtoAdd, 1, "Rice and Pasta")

Comment: Problem become when you have two or more CollectionModel inside CategoryModel

Comment: @S.P. Do you want to reduce the attribute `collections` in a `CategoryModel` to only those matching the condition? I thought you wanted all `CategoryModel`s that have at least one matching `CollectionModel` and then take the full `CategoryModel`...

Comment: Yes, I only want the CategoryModel whose CollectionModel match with the TextToSearch, and only the CollectionModel that match. If you have more CollectionModel in the CategoryModel the others have to be declined. Do you understand me?

Comment: Do you think that is possible?

Comment: @S.P. Yes, I understand and I think it's possible, but I will need some time to figure out how... Spend the mean time figuring out possible solutions yourself ;-)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying. If I get the solution I let you know

Comment: @S.P. I finally found a solution, but it's not really perfect... Check it out if you have time.

Comment: Take a look at the answer of Tenfour04, I think that is more clean approach. What do you think?

Comment: @S.P. Yes, that's definitely better... I would use that and accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
collection.reduce { acc, list ->  list.filter { it.name.contains(textToSearch.capitalize()) } }
```

Comment: I've tried but getting an error in .reduce. Take a look to my update question that I've attached a screenshot with the error

Comment: Just specify generic types `collection.reduce<List<CollectionModel>, List<CollectionModel>> { ... }`

Comment: I'm not be able to put correctly the generic types, sorry

Comment: private var collection: List<CategoryModel> = emptyList()

Comment: what about this logic? `collection.filter { it.collections.any { it.name.contains(textToSearch.capitalize()) } }`

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is using nested filter

```
  val list = mutableListOf<CategoryModel>()
    val filteredlist = list.filter {
        val sublist = it.collections.filter {
            it.name == "your text here..."
        }
        return@filter it.collections == sublist

    }
```